# fail to compile https://github.com/Polidea/RxAndroidBle

Tags: rxandroidble

i git clone this repository, and build it in android studio 3.4. it gives me such error:

Method com/github/jengelman/gradle/plugins/shadow/internal/DependencyFileCollection.getBuildDependencies()Lorg/gradle/api/tasks/TaskDependency; is abstract

so what's wrong with it?

Comment: Did you update `Android Gradle Plugin` after cloning the repository?

Comment: yes, i've changed File→Project Structure→Project→Gradle Version  to "5.4.1" , but the problem still exists. @Dariusz Seweryn

Comment: You should not modify the source if you want to have it built. If you have updated Gradle then the shadow plugin will not be compatible.

Comment: Have you solved the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Per https://github.com/johnrengelman/shadow/issues/447, just update `dependencies.gradle`'s `shadowPluginVersion` to the latest (currently 5.1.0) and things should start working again.